# Problems with C++ openCV file opening

Tags: c++, image, visual-studio-2010, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I have done numerous attempts and I can't seem to get simple code working. I have installed all the libraries correctly, the include path is correct, I have tried with Visual studio 2012 and am now on 2010. For some reason this works:

```
IplImage* img1 = cvLoadImage("C:\\Users\\Mota\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\Stabilization\\Stabilization\\Law.jpg");
```

img1 loads correctly.

However, if I try it with C++:

```
Mat img = imread("C:\\Users\\Mota\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\Stabilization\\Stabilization\\Law.jpg");
```

Then my application crashes with a message saying "OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size....)
So with the SAME path, I have two different results. I've been on this problem for a while now, does anyone knows what I could do? Is there something wrong with my C++ libraries? 
It's the same thing with videos, or anything that needs to load from a file.

Thanks

Comment: imread() takes a std::string as argument. please check, if you're linking the correct opencv libs (debug/release). it's definitely a linker problem.

Comment: Yes the path is correct and is a string "C:\\Users\\Mota\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\Stabilization\\Stabilization\\Law.jpg"

Comment: And my libs are the following

Comment: opencv_core249.lib
opencv_imgproc249.lib
opencv_highgui249.lib
opencv_ml249.lib
opencv_video249.lib
opencv_features2d249.lib
opencv_calib3d249.lib
opencv_objdetect249.lib
opencv_contrib249.lib
opencv_legacy249.lib
opencv_flann249.lib
opencv_calib3d249d.lib
opencv_contrib249d.lib
opencv_core249d.lib
opencv_features2d249d.lib
opencv_flann249d.lib
opencv_gpu249d.lib
opencv_highgui249d.lib
opencv_imgproc249d.lib
opencv_legacy249d.lib
opencv_ml249d.lib
opencv_nonfree249d.lib
opencv_objdetect249d.lib
opencv_photo249d.lib
opencv_stitching249d.lib
opencv_video249d.lib
opencv_videostab249d.lib

Comment: do *not* mix debug/release libs

Comment: (your path 'looked' wrong, because you forgot to format the code lines properly)

Comment: Removing the release libraries did it, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can try by giving path using forward slash like this,

```
Mat img = imread("//home//Desktop//OpenCV//1.jpg")
```